# Android - Load external .jar at runtime

Tags: java, android, urlclassloader

I want to load external library at runtime.

Here is the source:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Load support library");
        File file = new File("/sdcard/lib/android-support-v4.jar");
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = {url};
        URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class clazz = cl.loadClass("android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat");
    }
}
```

This library is Google's support library.
It is located at "/sdcard/lib/android-support-v4.jar".

I want to get "android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat" Class, but source always throw ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [JCL class loader framework](https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL).
usage example:

```
JarClassLoader jcl = new JarClassLoader();  
jcl.add("myjar.jar"); //Load jar file  
jcl.add(new URL("http://myserver.com/myjar.jar")); //Load jar from a URL  
jcl.add(new FileInputStream("myotherjar.jar")); //Load jar file from stream  
jcl.add("myclassfolder/"); //Load class folder  
jcl.add("myjarlib/"); //Recursively load all jar files in the folder/sub-folder(s)  

JclObjectFactory factory = JclObjectFactory.getInstance();  

//Create object of loaded class  
Object obj = factory.create(jcl,"mypackage.MyClass");
```

Comment: Is there no way to load external library without using other framework? I don't want to add other library..